# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Task already exists in this worker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How to fix this?

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Task already exists in this worker

We have set up kafka and kafka-connect on single server and all my connector are giving above error.

Also after restarting the connect service all the workers are stuck in unassigned mode.

Comment: Which connector are you trying to use?  Where are you seeing that? In the `/status` endpoint of the connector or when you POST the config? Can you please check your worker logs on the server? Also, not important here, but Kafka Connect should ideally not run on the same machine as the broker (you wouldn't run other consumer/producers on your brokers)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error myself and mananged to fix it by SSH-ing to the Connect server reporting the error, stopping all running instances of Kafka Connect e.g. `sudo systemctl stop kafka-connect`, or `SIGTERM` it

```
# ps -ef | grep java | grep Connect | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
<id>
# kill <id>
```

Then start it back up via `systemctl start kafka-connect`, or `connect-distributed`

Alternatively, you could also try HTTP `DELETE` & re-`POST` the connector config.